# what is the Way to get the messages that were displayed in SQLManagementStudio after executing a query in C#(programming)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to derive the text in "Messages" part to a string variable in C#.net after executing the query from my program.

Like,

```
int messag = convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteNonQuery())
```

which returns the no. of rows affected, the same way I would like to retrieve the text from "Messages" part to a string variable when executed like this.

Is that really possible?

[image: SQL query execution message]

Comment: This may help you :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724404/set-nocount-on-and-reading-messages-using-c-sharp-and-ado-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach event handlers for when an error or info is reported, like explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809529/how-can-i-get-the-return-value-from-sql-server-system-message).

```
namespace Test
{
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    public class Program
    {
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 2)
            {
                Usage();
                return 1;
            }

            var conn = args[0];
            var sqlText = args[1];
            ShowSqlErrorsAndInfo(conn, sqlText);

            return 0;
        }

        private static void Usage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: sqlServerConnectionString sqlCommand");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("   example:  \"Data Source=.;Integrated Security=true\" \"DBCC CHECKDB\"");
        }

        public static void ShowSqlErrorsAndInfo(string connectionString, string query)
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.StateChange += OnStateChange;
                connection.InfoMessage += OnInfoMessage;

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                try
                {
                    command.Connection.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("Command execution starting.");
                    SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Rows returned.");
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            for (int idx = 0; idx < dr.FieldCount; idx++)
                            {
                                Console.Write("{0} ", dr[idx].ToString());
                            }

                            Console.WriteLine();
                        }
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Command execution complete.");
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    DisplaySqlErrors(ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    command.Connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        private static void DisplaySqlErrors(SqlException exception)
        {
            foreach (SqlError err in exception.Errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}", err.Message);
            }
        }

        private static void OnInfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (SqlError info in e.Errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("INFO: {0}", info.Message);
            }
        }

        private static void OnStateChange(object sender, StateChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connection state changed: {0} => {1}", e.OriginalState, e.CurrentState);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please add helpfull data from the link ,so this answer will look complete