# Verification of backup file .bak using Microsoft.Management.Smo

Tags: c#, sql

I backup a database using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo. My question is how to verify that the backup file is restorable and will work properly. After spending some time on the internet, I found that the following T-SQL verifies but is there a way in Microsoft.Management.Smo assembly. I am expecting some code sample.

```
RESTORE VERIFYONLY
FROM DISK = 'C:\Test\Test.bak'
WITH CHECKSUM
```

Below is my code samples.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

namespace BackupApplication
{
    class DatabaseBackup
    {    
        public void DoDataBaseBackup()
        {    
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ToString();
            SqlConnection connecton = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection(connecton);
            Server myServer = new Server(serverConnection);

            //Using windows authentication                
            myServer.ConnectionContext.Connect();

            Database myDatabase = myServer.Databases[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseNameToBackup"]];

            //Backup operation
            Backup bkpDBFull = new Backup();
            /* Specify whether you want to back up database or files or log */
            bkpDBFull.Action = BackupActionType.Database;

            /* Specify the name of the database to back up */
            bkpDBFull.Database = myDatabase.Name;

            /* You can take backup on several media type (disk or tape), here I am
             * using File type and storing backup on the file system */
            string destinationFolderForDatabase = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DestinationFolderForDatabase"];
            bkpDBFull.Devices.AddDevice(destinationFolderForDatabase, DeviceType.File);
            bkpDBFull.BackupSetName = "Test database Backup";
            bkpDBFull.BackupSetDescription = "test database - Full Backup";


            /* You can specify the expiration date for your backup data
             * after that date backup data would not be relevant */
            bkpDBFull.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(10);

            /* You can specify Initialize = false (default) to create a new 
             * backup set which will be appended as last backup set on the media. You
             * can specify Initialize = true to make the backup as first set on the
             * medium and to overwrite any other existing backup sets if the all the
             * backup sets have expired and specified backup set name matches with
             * the name on the medium */
            bkpDBFull.Initialize = false;

            /* You can specify Incremental = false (default) to perform full backup or Incremental = true to perform differential backup since most recent full backup */
            bkpDBFull.Incremental = false;

            /* Wiring up events for progress monitoring */
            bkpDBFull.PercentComplete += CompletionStatusInPercent;
            bkpDBFull.Complete += Backup_Completed;

            /* SqlBackup method starts to take back up
             * You can also use SqlBackupAsync method to perform the backup 
             * operation asynchronously */
            bkpDBFull.SqlBackup(myServer);

            if (myServer.ConnectionContext.IsOpen)
            {
                myServer.ConnectionContext.Disconnect();
            }
        }

        private void Backup_Completed(object sender, ServerMessageEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TestDatabase Backup Completed.");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Error.Message);            
        }

        private void CompletionStatusInPercent(object sender, PercentCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Percent completed: {0}%.", e.Percent);
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.CS**

```
using System;   

namespace BackupApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DatabaseBackup databaseBackup = new DatabaseBackup();
            databaseBackup.DoDataBaseBackup();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**App.Config**

```
<connectionStrings>     
    <add name="TestDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=SSPI"/>
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
    <add key="DestinationFolderForDatabase" value="C:\Test.bak"/>
    <add key="DatabaseNameToBackup" value="Test"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `.bak is validate or not`?

Comment: _"I am expecting some code sample."_ - well, here's some documentation with a sample. [Restore.SqlVerify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms209758.aspx) has a sample of _"how to create a backup and verify that it is readable and complete."_, though you'd probably want to use [the overload that returns error messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms209837.aspx)

Comment: Once the back up complete create a `Restore` and verify the same `BackupDeviceItem` used to create the backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code helps to verify the backup file is restorable.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

namespace BackupApplication
{
    class DatabaseBackup
    {    
        public void DoDataBaseBackup()
        {    
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ToString();
            SqlConnection connecton = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection(connecton);
            Server myServer = new Server(serverConnection);

            //Using windows authentication                
            myServer.ConnectionContext.Connect();

            Database myDatabase = myServer.Databases[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseNameToBackup"]];

            //Backup operation
            Backup bkpDBFull = new Backup();
            /* Specify whether you want to back up database or files or log */
            bkpDBFull.Action = BackupActionType.Database;

            /* Specify the name of the database to back up */
            bkpDBFull.Database = myDatabase.Name;

            /* You can take backup on several media type (disk or tape), here I am
             * using File type and storing backup on the file system */
            string destinationFolderForDatabase = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DestinationFolderForDatabase"];
            bkpDBFull.Devices.AddDevice(destinationFolderForDatabase, DeviceType.File);
            bkpDBFull.BackupSetName = "Test database Backup";
            bkpDBFull.BackupSetDescription = "test database - Full Backup";


            /* You can specify the expiration date for your backup data
             * after that date backup data would not be relevant */
            bkpDBFull.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(10);

            /* You can specify Initialize = false (default) to create a new 
             * backup set which will be appended as last backup set on the media. You
             * can specify Initialize = true to make the backup as first set on the
             * medium and to overwrite any other existing backup sets if the all the
             * backup sets have expired and specified backup set name matches with
             * the name on the medium */
            bkpDBFull.Initialize = false;

            /* You can specify Incremental = false (default) to perform full backup or Incremental = true to perform differential backup since most recent full backup */
            bkpDBFull.Incremental = false;

            /* Wiring up events for progress monitoring */
            bkpDBFull.PercentComplete += CompletionStatusInPercent;
            bkpDBFull.Complete += Backup_Completed;

            /* SqlBackup method starts to take back up
             * You can also use SqlBackupAsync method to perform the backup 
             * operation asynchronously */
            bkpDBFull.SqlBackup(myServer);

    Restore restore = new Restore();
    restore.Devices.AddDevice(@"C:\Test.bak", DeviceType.File);
    restore.Database = "Test2012";
    Console.WriteLine(restore.SqlVerify(myServer).ToString());
            if (myServer.ConnectionContext.IsOpen)
            {
                myServer.ConnectionContext.Disconnect();
            }
        }

        private void Backup_Completed(object sender, ServerMessageEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TestDatabase Backup Completed.");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Error.Message);            
        }

        private void CompletionStatusInPercent(object sender, PercentCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Percent completed: {0}%.", e.Percent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Verifying can mean a variety of things; your particular answer and code samples are dependent on what way you want to go.
Here are a few methods:

1. Use System.IO and check if file exists.
2. SMO can be utilized with [SqlVerify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms209758(v=sql.110).aspx)
3. Sql Client can be used with Restore Verify [return value from Sql Server system message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809529/how-can-i-get-the-return-value-from-sql-server-system-message)