# How can I see if a SQL query has properly executed without errors?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am creating a program which detaches a database.

How can I check to see whether or not the stored procedure has run without errors so I can confirm to the user it is fully finished.

I'm using a `try catch` around the execution, but i'm not 100% certain this will return all internal errors?

My concern is that if I write:

```
try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("it has finished");
}
catch (exception ex)
{
ex.ToString();
}
```

Isn't reliable

my Command:

```
 return "sp_detach_db '" + dbType[db] + "', 'true'";
```

Comment: which engine are you  usin  sql server oracle or mysql

Comment: Please, tag your dbms

Comment: It is reliable. If an exception is thrown, it will catch it.

Comment: Wouldn't any unhandled exceptions in the PL/SQL bubble up to .NET? Assume a try/catch will take care of it...

Comment: @McNets Done, apologies.

Comment: Have you tried it? Write a stored procedure that divides 1 by 0, call it, and see what happens?

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery will return the number of row affected.  Depending on what your stored procedure does you might want to check you have more than 0 rows affected

Comment: For `sp_detach_db`, you might want to also check the procesure's return value - 0 (success) or 1 (failure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code is fine (try/catch)...the string you're passing in is the tricky part of what you're trying to do.  I would look at this answer to figure out of the command returned a 0 or 1........ if the return value is 1, then you will throw a new exception.

[Calling stored procedure with return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210027/calling-stored-procedure-with-return-value/6210055#6210055)

As per the documentation: you are after the RETURN_CODE.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-detach-db-transact-sql

```
Return Code Values
0 (success) or 1 (failure)
Result Sets
None
```

pseudo c# code

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("MyString"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("sp_detach_db '{0}', 'true'", myDatabaseName); /* where myDatabaseName is a string */
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


    var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnVal", SqlDbType.Int);
    returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    object result = returnParameter.Value;
    int resultInt = Convert.ToInt32(result);
    if( 0 != resultInt )
    { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("detach failed");}
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks very much

Comment: Look at Gary's answer (same question I posted earlier) as well.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210027/calling-stored-procedure-with-return-value/25674912#25674912  I think that's what I had in-mind when I posted the code.

Answer (score 1):

If your stored procedure is able to raise an exception, you can catch it in your 
try-catch block.

```
create procedure MySp
as
begin

      <some operation>

      if @@error <> 0
      begin
            rollback;
            raiserror('error message', 16, 1);
            return -1;
     end

     return 0;
end
```

Comment: please see my new comments for the SP. It's a default SQL one which I don't want to amend if possible as this will be used on 100's of machines.

Comment: This code has a rollback.  The template has no begin-tran or commit-tran.  IMHO, this is writing code for the sake of writing code...the stored procedure could call the sp_detach_db, but the contents of the stored procedure could be as simple as "return sp_detach_db (args)".. the extra @@error check is unnecessary.  Any exception would simply bubble up to c#... and the c# code still needs to find the return_code.....(as per my answer)  Again, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value of ExecuteNonQuery(), which returns an Int for Rows Affected
You can also parse the [Status Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809529/how-can-i-get-the-return-value-from-sql-server-system-message) from SQL as well to check error values